# How to show that $X$ is covered by rational curves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

I am reading a paper, there is a statement like this:
Maybe not a good question for MO.
Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface, let $|D|$ be a linear system having moving component $M$. Assume that each irreducible component of $D$ is a smooth rational curve. Then $X$ is covered by rational curves.

Geometrically or by intuition, it looks fine. But I do not know how to make this statement and proof rigorous. I think what I am not quite sure is what the meaning of his "covered by rational curves". From the paper, it looks like he wants to say that $X$ is uniruled etc.

Comment: It seems to me that there is a missing condition. For example take a nodal rational curve $D$ in a polarised K3 $(X, H)$ with $D$ linearly equivalent to $H$

Comment: @Frank, I forget to say that $D$ is smooth rational curve

Comment: Then in this case, assuming $M$ is non-trivial, it must be that there is at least one component $R$ of $D$ so that $R^2>0$ (eg from the Zariski decomposition). Hence you have a moving rational curve. To be more formal, there is a number of ways to conclude, but since you mentioned uniruledness, we get in particular that the normal bundle $N_{R/X}$ is an ample bundle which gives uniruledness

Comment: @Frank, thanks very much, all the others are clear but not sure about the ampleness of normal bundle implies uniruledness. Can you elaborate it a little bit? By the way, is there any reference talking about various equivalent about uniruledness, or relations with unirational, rational ,rational connected.

Comment: A great introduction to these things can be found in Debarre's notes https://www.math.ens.fr/~debarre/M2.pdf (or see his or Kollar's book for further details). For example what I mentioned seems to also appear at the bottom of page 97.

Comment: Thank u frank, what I thought about is to based on ur argument using miyakao you

Comment: What u said is absolutely right,thanks for recommendation

Comment: Hi Shizhuo,  I am not sure if it is complicated to write down the proof, using Miyaoka-Yau.  could you write it down?